# How to enforce Windows and Linux compatibility in my open source python project?

Tags: python, continuous-integration, devops, continuous-deployment

I'm working on a big project involvoing more than 100 programmers. We work in a model of code owners, and each group is working on their own code segment.

There are some rules that I have to enforce:

1. The code must be compatible with python6 (compatible for both 2 and 3)
2. The code must be compatible with linux and windows

In order to check rule number 1, I use `futurize` in my CI. That works fine to check the compatibility.

I also need to find a way to check the Linux/Windows issue, are there any tools I can use to check it? The only thing I have in my mind right now is to use a Windows agent in my CI, but I would like to have a static analysis for the enforcement of this rule.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Maybe I missed something but what is Python6 ?

Comment: @OlvinRoght, is the Python version that comes after Python 5.x. I see you are still in the '20s!  Anyway I'm pretty sure it was a typo.

Comment: @OlvinRoght its mean i compatible for both 2 and 3, thats what the package named six called like it

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: @Rob well, I'm Not looking for a specific tool, Just any solution to my problem, even a way to write my own tool for that

Comment: Linux is a very broad term. What works on arch might fail in debian

Answer (score -1):

The only way to ensure compatibility of code in a given environment is to test it thoroughly in said environment. Use a CI runner to execute your test suite with a test matrix. Popular services for CI are Github Actions, Gitlab CI, Jenkins, CircleCI, Travis CI, drone, tox, and many more.

Here's an example of Celery's CI suite, based on Github Actions, which use a matrix of python versions and operating systems.

https://github.com/celery/celery/blob/master/.github/workflows/python-package.yml#L28-L30

Comment: I'm already doing it, i asked for static way to do it.

Comment: So you're saying you want some sort of static tool, `./check_if_codebase_supports_windows` you can run which will assert that the python code is Windows compatible? Yeah, no such thing exists, especially if you are supporting 2.x, which makes awareness of string codecs even harder. There's too many ways in which a Python codebase can do dynamic things which could break in Windows. The best you could do is maybe identify certain libraries or function calls which are known to be bad, and banlist them.

Comment: well, thats why i open this question :)